# Unable to get the front end template params in joomla user event plugin

Tags: templates, plugins, joomla, parameters

Unable to get the template param of logo in onUserBeforeSave event plugin...

```
public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg){

  $app        = JFactory::getApplication();
  $template   = $app->getTemplate(true);
  $params     = $template->params;
  $variable   = $params->get('logo');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're getting any errors with your current code, however I'm sure the following will work as I have just tested it:

```
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;
$variable = $params->get('logo');

echo $variable;
```

Comment: I can able to get the logo using this code on component..
but its not working in user event plugin only